# Get number of child from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the number of children as well as their names.

Here's my data Image : [image: Data structure]

I want to get no of children under Day 1 (in image there are 3 children under Day 1 : match 1, match 2 & match 3). and also their names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get those three children under `Day 1` node, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dayOneRef = rootRef.child("Tournaments").child("PMAS").child("Day 1");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Number of children: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String month = ds.getKey();
            Log.d(TAG, month);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
dayOneRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output in the console will be:

```
Number of children: 3
match 1
match 2
match 3
```

Answer (score 0):

retrieve childs of Day 1 to an array and count the array that ll be the no of child.

Answer (score 0):

> - You need to do add nested valuelister
> - valueEventListener give you list of days you played game
> - add another lister to days that will give you all matches you played on a day.
> - add another listnet that give you detail about the match

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference addressRef = rootRef.child("Tournament").child("PMAS"); // set the PMAS data child observer
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         Log.d(TAG, "total days count: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        // dataSnapshot.getChildren()  give all the days e.g day 1,day 2  // you can get your count here
          for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               String key = ds.getKey();  // get key as day 1 

            // add one more observer that give you days matches e.g  
            DatabaseReference childRef = rootRef.child("Tournament").child("PMAS").child(key);  //where key = e.g day 1                  
            // add new listent that give you detail of address 
            childRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(dayValueventListner);   // This value event lister give you child matches  

            /**
            * For matches add dayvalueevent listent that give you all matches count.
            **/

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
addressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```